# serialize a script

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, xaml

i have this

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var playlist = [
  { 
    artist : "Lady Gaga",
    title : "Lady Gaga  Just Dance remix",
    type : "sound",
    file : "http://news.yzwb.net/dianzibao/2010-12-26/58CABECF-0579-42A1-9733-B80F2EDFE1E3.mp3",
    id : "de0d4d6842d9354cdc2cbdefd34ab2c7" 
  }
  ,
  { 
    artist : "Dj schmolli",
    title : "Scream aim dance bullet for lady gaga lady gaga just dance vs bullet for my valentine scream aim fire",
    type : "sound",
    file : "http://www.culturebully.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/DJ Schmolli - Scream Aim Dance (Bullet For Lady Gaga).mp3",
    id : "004f99f5ff88aa5d376da40880cd4688" 
  },
....>
```

I want to get those links which end with '.mp3' any ideas please?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with regular expressions.

The other way would be using the string manipulation functions in .NET:

Split the string with `String.Split` on the " character, this will give you an array of strings. 
Check every other item in the resulting array (these will be the strings that were inside the quotes).
If the string ends in .mp3 (use `String.EndsWith`) then it is a link to an mp3 file.